# Why does no one use the notation $f(x)^2$?

Tags: functions, notation

It seems to me that "$f(x)^2$" couldn't mean anything other than "$[f(x)]^2$", so there shouldn't be any ambiguity involved, but people always tend to put an extra pair of brackets around the "$f(x)$" everywhere I see it squared. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Perhaps because some people think $f (x)^2$ could mean $f (x^2)$. This is reasonable when $x$ is some big complicated expression like $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$...

Comment: Isn't the usual notation "$f^2(x)$?"

Comment: I think $f(x)^2$ just *looks* quite ugly (maybe because I don't immediately see what's being squared exactly at a glance)... That's certainly the reason why *I* prefer extra brackets.

Comment: @Sam But it's not ugly for a programmer. ;)

For me it's definitely $f(x)\,f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

The primary concern is that the parenthesized quantity will be viewed as squared, rather than the function. There can be ambiguity when you're unsure of whether the person is being sloppy by considering the argument as squared and just leaving off the brackets around $(x)^2$.

Comment: Not sure, though, if anyone worth reading would be making *that* kind of mistake. ha ha, just my opinion though.

Comment: Sure, in publications. If I'm handed a set of notes though, there's no telling what kind of shorthand conventions may be in use.